# Every Nonzero Direction at $x$ is Feasible $\iff$ $x$ lies in the Interior of the Set

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-analysis

I am reading a book on linear optimization and I am stuck in the following problem:

> Suppose $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set and $x^0\in\Omega$. Prove $x^0\in int(\Omega)$ if and only if $F_{x^0}^{\Omega} = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$.

The book defines $F_{x^0}^{\Omega}$ the set of Feasible Directions at $x^0$:
$$v\in F_{x^0}^{\Omega} \iff v\neq 0 \quad and \quad \exists \delta >0 \quad s.t. \quad \forall \lambda \in [0,\delta] \quad x^0+\lambda v\in \Omega.$$

**My Attempt:**
$$x^0\in int(\Omega) \implies \exists \epsilon >0 \quad s.t. \quad B_{x^0}(\epsilon) \subset \Omega \implies \forall v\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} \quad \forall \lambda\in[0,\frac{\epsilon}{2||v||}] \quad x^0+\lambda v \in \Omega$$
Thus $v\in F_{x^0}^{\Omega}$.

First of all, this proof does not require convexity of $\Omega$. Is it correct?
Secondly, I do not know how to prove the inverse argument.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convexity of the domain (and also the finite dimensionality of the space) is needed for the other direction.

If every non-zero direction at $x^0$ is feasible  then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
 x^0 \pm \delta e_j \in \Omega, \, (1 \le j \le n)
$$
where $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ are the unit vectors of $\Bbb R^n$. It follows that the convex hull of those points is a subset of $\Omega$, and that contains an open neighborhood of $x^0$.

Without the convexity of $\Omega$ this conclusion does not necessarily hold. A counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$ is the set
$$
\Omega = \{ (x, y) \mid y = 0 \text{ or } |y| > x^2 \} \, .
$$
[image]

Every direction at $(0, 0)$ is feasible, but $(0, 0)$ is not an interior point of the set.

Similar counterexamples can be constructed in all dimensions $n \ge 2$. The convexity is *not* needed in one dimension.

Comment: Note that we take minimum of finitely many direction feasibility constants. So finite dimensionality is also essential I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, you are completely right. The question is about $\Bbb R^n$, but I have added it as a remark. Thanks!

Comment: I know the original setting but I was just pointing out that the finite dimensions are used subtly.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The result is also true in infinite-dimensional Banach spaces (as corollary of Baire theorem)